# SVN command line: svnlook history mypath, can't open file

Tags: svn, svnlook

I use this command to display the history of commits.

`svnlook history -r 2 mypath`

and I get this:

`svnlook: Can't open file 'mypath/format': No such file or directory`

I'm sure that "mypath" is correct. I also tried going into deeper directories. I tried with absolute and relative paths, I tried with the -r option and without but I always get the same result.

Comment: Are you trying to execute this on a machine where the repository is physically located?

Comment: @djdy On my own PC where the working copy is. Is this a server command? If yes, how could I achieve the same from local terminal?

Comment: `svnlook` is a server command.  You can use `svn` to retrieve whatever data you need from the working copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `svnlook` command is used on the server that is hosting the repository (i.e., it's not what you need).

You can use `svn` to query the working copy for what data you're looking for.  Refer to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.history.html and check out `svn log` or `svn diff` to get a history of the changes.